# Installing libapache2-mod-fastcgi in ubuntu 14.04, package not available

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I'm having trouble installing the libapache2-mod-fastcgi module which is required in order for me to use PHP-FPM with Apache. When I try to install using this command

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

which results in this error.

```
Package libapache2-mod-fastcgi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate
```

My sources.list looks like this

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe $
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
#
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main


## distribution.
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
```

I have tried following the directions listed here but I just get errors when I run sudo apt-get update so I removed those repositories because it made no difference I still couldn't install the module and it wasn't fetching anything.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with build-essential, although it doesn't happen consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add multiverse in your `sources.list`, and then `apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get update`. It should do the trick.